# How do I use LINQ to apply a calculation to multiple arrays

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm working a program to perform calculations on multiple raster datasets. I can extract each dataset to an array of type double and I was able to work out how to perform calculations on two arrays at once using LINQ's dynamic expressions:

```
        Dim rasterAParam As System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Double), "A")
        Dim rasterBParam As System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(Double), "B")
        Dim params As List(Of System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression) = New List(Of ParameterExpression)
        params.Add(rasterAParam)
        params.Add(rasterBParam)
        DIm calcString as String = "A + B * 2"

        Dim lambda As LambdaExpression = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(params.ToArray(), Nothing, calcString)            

        Dim lambdaFunc As Func(Of Double, Double, Double) = lambda.Compile


        rasterContentsA = rasterContentsA.Zip(rasterContentsB, lambdaFunc).ToArray
```

Now I need to expand this so that I can perform operations on 3 or more rasters with the one statement. Problem is the zip function only works with two inputs at once. I have noticed that the lambdaExpression class has an option to invoke the function dynamically but that would only be for individual double values, not arrays of them.

Any idea on how I can do this please?

Comment: Chain `Zip` and use an intermediate lambda and a lambda wrapper: `A.Zip(B, (a,b) => (a,b)).Zip(C, (ab,c) => lambdaFunc(ab.a,ab.b,c))`.

Comment: Sorry, VB.Net version: `A.Zip(B, Function(a,b) (a,b)).Zip(C, Function(ab,c) lambdaFunc(ab.a,ab.b,c))`

Comment: Thanks. I ended up working out a different method using LINQ Expressions. I still had to resort to some for loops but it seems to work.